# Show message Box in .net console application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, console-application, messagebox

How to show a message box in a .net c# or vb **console application** ?
Something like:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
 MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello")
MsgBox("Hello")
```

in c# and vb respectively.
 Is it possible?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

We can show a message box in a console application. But first include this  reference in your vb.net or c# console application

```
System.Windows.Forms;
```

**Reference:**

To add reference in vb.net program right click (in solution explorer) on your project name-> then add reference-> then .Net-> then select System.Windows.Forms.
To add reference in c# program right click in your project folders shown in solution explorer on add references-> .Net -> select System.Windows.Forms.

then you can do the below code for  c# console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

For the vb.net application you can simply code after inclusion of above mentioned reference

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        MsgBox("Hello")
        Console.ReadKey()


    End Sub

End Module
```

Adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314811/4282901) answer to a related question.

Comment: Move Add reference explanation top because code is depended on reference

Answer (score 35):

To have a simple message box inside your console application you can follow the below steps.

1. Create a property with attribute of

   ```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr h, string m, string c, int type);
   ```
2. User the property to call the message box.

   ```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace AllKeys
    {
        public class Program
        {
            [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr h, string m, string c, int type);

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                MessageBox((IntPtr)0, "Your Message", "My Message Box", 0);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: I think this answer must be accepted answer, because we need't add windows form application's dependencies to console app (For example using System.Windows.Forms;)

Answer (score 5):

For **.NET 5** and **.NET 6** =>

1. Create the console app the regular way.
2. Update the TargetFramework in .csproj with one of these:

   <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>

   <!--OR-->

   <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
3. Add this to .csproj:

   <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>

   <!-- AND/OR -->

   <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
4. Compile the app, so the referenced .NET dlls get updated.
5. For the WPF message box add **using System.Windows;** and for the Windows Forms message box add **using System.Windows.Forms;** on the top of your code file. Then, just make calls to **MessageBox.Show("...")**

Comment: Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop

Comment: Alos, if you want to hide the console window, here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853629/hide-console-window-in-c-sharp-console-application

Answer (score 4):

In C# add the reference "PresentationFramework" in the project. Next in the class that you need the `MessageBox` add

```
using System.Windows;
```

also you can call the `MessageBox` class without the using like that:

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Stackoverflow");
```