# How can I create Yes/No dialog in C# .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

So I tryed to make a simple text game.And I wanted to do Yes/No dialong I was trying to figure this out for 2 hours, but i didn't find any solution to my problem. I'm total beginner, so I don't know much about coding.

### I was trying to achive it trough "bool" bot it wasnt the right option. Obviousli.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TEXTRPG

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Greetings, stranger.");

            Console.ReadKey();

            Console.WriteLine("I've came here to give you a quest.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Do you accept?");
            //Yes/No
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You can't have a dialog for a console application, thats a windows form application.

Comment: use `Console.ReadLine` to get text.

Comment: You can ask for user input through the console and accept a Yes/No text

Comment: @JayMason dialog, as in a text adventure where you talk with a character and have a dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, you can have a MessageBox shown in a console application, weird but possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326042/show-message-box-in-net-console-application

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample

```
do {
        Console.Write("Do you accept? [y/n] ");
        response = Console.ReadKey(false).Key;
        if (response != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            Console.WriteLine();
    } while (response != ConsoleKey.Y && response != ConsoleKey.N);
```